# Can pole dancing constrict veins and worsen varicose veins?

Tags: dancing

I am a young girl in her twenties and have some visible, dark colored veins on my calves. I want to take up pole dancing but am worried that the rubbing against the pole and tight hugging will worsen my case. Does anyone know whether this holds truth or should I proceed without worrying?

Comment: Watching https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/19803/8039 may answer some of your questions. A doctor who specializes in varicose veins discusses the general case of exercise and varicose veins. He don't address pole dancing, but he recommends any wrestling that doesn't involve vigorous cardio with your legs moving above your head due to the rare risk of blood clots (he says it's more theoretical), and to also watch for phlebitis (itching).